# How to group legend handles in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, legend

I was wondering how I can produce such fancy legends in `matplotlib`. In particular, I'd like to know how to group, for example, both solid and dashed blue lines which correspond to $\tau=10$ side by side, or all dashed (or solid) lines together as in the lower part of the legend.

[image]

The image is taken from [this arxiv paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03367.pdf).

Comment: The [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#multiple-legends-on-the-same-axes) is very detailled. I suggest trying to create what you want to achieve and coming back with a specific problem.

Comment: Also note that apart from creating an explicit legend, you could mimic it drawing extra lines and placing texts onto the plot.

Comment: See also [seaborn's approach](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) in dealing with combinating line styles, colors and thicknesses. The approach of the posts plot will only work when there are very few colors and styles to combine. It is a custom solution for a particular situation.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC . I have been using seaborn style legend for a while. But here, I'm particularly asking for the syntax of legend grouping, not alternatives.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is a syntax for the type of legend you are asking. It will be a lot of custom code, with only limited use. See e.g. [Matplotlib PatchCollection to Legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224611/matplotlib-patchcollection-to-legend) about creating custom legend handlers.

Comment: Thanks again @JohanC. This post was very helpful. I could do what I wanted to. I'll post the answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on my original post, I could come up with a script that does the grouping, albeit as mentioned, not as straightforwardly as I thought. The script is essentially an adapted version of the other answer on SO.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib import patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

class AnyObject(object):
    pass

class AnyObjectHandler(object):
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        
        codes = [Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO]
        
        # the following lines unfortunately may not be refactored
        verts1 = [(x0, y0+0.25*height),(x0 + width, y0+0.25*height)]
        verts2 = [(x0, y0+0.75*height),(x0 + width, y0+0.75*height)]
        
        path1 = Path(verts1,codes)
        path2 = Path(verts2,codes)
        
        patch1 = mpatches.PathPatch(path1)
        patch2 = mpatches.PathPatch(path2,ls='--',)
        patch = PatchCollection([patch1,patch2],match_original=True)

        handlebox.add_artist(patch)
        return patch
    

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.legend([AnyObject()], ['My grouped handlers'],
          handler_map={AnyObject: AnyObjectHandler()})
```

while leads to

[image]

---

### Take-home messages

1. The legend docs specifies a more natural way to group the entries using `HandlerTuple` (example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#legend-handlers)). But since `mpl` places the markers horizontally, such an approach is orthogonal to what I wished :). If it doesn't bother you, go for that option first.
2. As far as I understood, custom legends are designed such that they don't exchange any information with the data you want to plots. For example, in my case, I cannot tell the `AnyObjectHandler` how many lines are going to be grouped, what are their `linestyle`, etc. It is a good decision for generality, with the expense of a (minimal) harm to the code refactoring.

Comment: See also the last example [in this tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/legend_demo.html)